# Update DB Table with Checkbox Values

Tags: sql, checkbox

This should be simple..but I am not having any luck using values found in checkbox to update DB table values.

I want to simply confirm that a player has placed a vintage poster on their social media page(s). If they have, they earn a few tokens towards gameplay. On the internal management dashboard there is a checkbox marked "Approved".  There can be multiple similar listings for multiple players. Depending on how many are approved, the query can return any number of entries, each of which is the id for each entry in the media table.

[screen grab of dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvzrQ.png)

The query should simply change the value of "confirm" from 0 to 1. At this point, they will earn some tokens, up to a maximum of 100 (https://rewildgame.toonstech.com/tokens)
Running the code below show that mediaID values are being passed, but the UPDATE isn't occurring.

```
<?php 

if(!empty($_POST['check_list'])) {
    foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $mediaID) {
            
$sql ="UPDATE media SET confirm = 1 WHERE id = $mediaID" ;
                                 
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Looks like you never execute the query.

Comment: Did you posted full code? Here you are just forming the query string but not executing it. You would need to connect to db using connection string and then execute this query.